# How to delete Firebase users

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have upgraded a Firebase app to the new version, so I see my Firebase at [console.firebase.google.com](http://console.firebase.google.com).

The console shows me a message `Wow, you have a lot of users! Because you have over 500 users, they aren't automatically displayed.` The only way to see any user details at all seems to be to search for a complete email address and that only works for users with a password.

I don't know how I came to have so many users, it's a development system and I am not aware of more than a dozen userIds. Regardless, I would like to **delete them all**.

I get the same message in a production system which also has less than 500 known  users, so I must have some that are not real - I want to be able to  view some details and **delete them one by one**.

[The Docs](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6400802) don't provide a solution for either requirement. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Hi! Please reach out via our [troubleshooting page](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) with information about your projects and we shall be able to help you.

Comment: Is anonymous login enabled in your project? If so, anonymous users are also counted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39909854/2254886 Check out my answer on here. It's not the correct answer, but it might save you a big headache.