# How to bulk delete Firebase anonymous users

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Due to my probable misuse of anonymous authentication (see [How to prevent Firebase anonymous user token from expiring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39640511/how-to-prevent-firebase-anonymous-user-token-from-expiring)) I have a lot of anonymous users in my app that I don't actually want.

I can't see any way to bulk delete these users. Do I have to do it manually one-by-one? Is there anyway to use the API to access user accounts and manipulate them for users other than the current user?

Comment: I have a slightly different case than this, but I use async await to delete anonymous users that signed in last six month ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837805/9605341

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way in the Firebase Console to bulk-delete users.

There is no API to bulk-delete users.

But there is administrative API that allows you to delete user accounts. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user

Comment: Bummer. I'm glad we only have 100 spurious users and not 10000! :-)

Comment: Do you know if an administrative API is in the works?

Comment: Any updates on this Frank?
Would be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: There is an admin API for user deletion!
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#deleteUser

Comment: Good one @nloewen, the Admin SDK has added User management functionality in the meantime. I updated my answer and added a link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808712/delete-all-users-from-firebase-auth-console/42467103#42467103

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen Does this mean we have to keep track of the UID of every anonymous users that we create?

Answer (score 17):

This code sample uses the Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js, and will delete any user that has no `providerData`, which means the user is anonymous:

```
function deleteAnonymousUsers(nextPageToken) {
 adminApp
    .auth()
    .listUsers(20, nextPageToken)
    .then(function(listUsersResult) {
      listUsersResult.users.forEach(function(userRecord) {
        if (userRecord.providerData.length === 0) { //this user is anonymous
         console.log(userRecord); // do your delete here
         adminApp.auth().deleteUser(userRecord.uid)
            .then(function() {
                console.log("Successfully deleted user");
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error deleting user:", error);
            });
        }
      });
      if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
        // List next batch of users.
        deleteAnonymousUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('Error listing users:', error);
    });
}
```

Comment: How do you stop anonymous users being created?

Comment: what do you put as the initial nextPageToken?

Comment: An update to this after a few years: since listUsersResult.users.forEach is an async function this could possibly spill over your writes/second quota, such that you'll need to run it several times to finish.

Comment: @SuperUberDuper 0 is initial nextPageToken. Disable anonymous auth in Firebase console

Answer (score 6):

I just wanted to add a method I just used to (sort-of) bulk-delete. Mostly because I felt clever after doing it and I am not that clever.

I downloaded a mouse-automation application that lets you record your mouse clicks then replay it automatically. I just deleted almost 1000 users while playing the piano lol.

I used [Macro Recorder](https://www.jitbit.com/macro-recorder/mouse-recorder/) and it worked like a charm. Just recorded a few iterations in the console of me deleting users, set it to repeat 500 times and walked away.

I know this isn't a very technical answer, but it saved me *hours* of monotonous mouse clicking so hopefully someone else looking for a way to bulk-delete will benefit from it as well. I hated the fact that there was no bulk-delete and *really* needed a way out of it. It only took about 20 manual deletes to realize there were apps that could do what I was doing.

Comment: I posted answer which does this with few lines of code without any dependency https://stackoverflow.com/a/70917483/1353874

Answer (score 6):

If you need to delete anonymous users from Firebase Console UI but don't want to go through the hassle of clicking on 250 users one by one, you can use the following code in your console on the screen that displays a table of users:

```js
rows = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td.auth-user-identifier-cell')).map(td => td.parentNode).filter((tr) => tr.innerText.includes('anonymous'))

var nextTick = null

function openContextMenu(tr) {
    console.log('openning menu')
    tr.querySelector('.edit-account-button').click()
    nextTick = deleteUser
}

function deleteUser() {
    console.log('deleting user')
    document.querySelector('.cdk-overlay-connected-position-bounding-box button:last-of-type').click()
    nextTick = confirmDelete
}

function confirmDelete() {
    console.log('confirming action')
    document.querySelector('.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper .confirm-button').click()
    nextTick = getUser
}

function getUser() {
    console.log('getting user')
    openContextMenu(rows.shift())
}

nextTick = getUser
step = 500
setInterval(() => {
    nextTick()
}, step)
```

This code essentially selects all rows that contain anonymous users and simulates the process of clicking on the three dots, deleting the account, and confirming the action in the modal that appears.

Before running the script, make sure to select 250 rows per page in the table's footer. After removing all anonymous users on one page, you'll need to manually go to the next page and rerun the script or code in another `tick` to paginate for you.

Keep in mind that it takes 1.5 seconds to delete one user (you can adjust this with the `step` variable, but I don't recommend going lower than 500ms due to potential UI animations).

Also, the script runs in the background, so you can multitask while it's running, such as watching YouTube videos.

Answer (score 3):

Update 2021:

I had around 10,000 anonymous users, and @regretoverflow's solution lead to exceeding the delete user quota. However, slightly tweaking the code to utilize the admin's deleteUsers([userId1, userId2, ...]) API works like a charm.

```
function deleteAnonymousUsers(nextPageToken: string | undefined) {
  firebaseAdmin
    .auth()
    .listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
    .then(function (listUsersResult) {
      const anonymousUsers: string[] = [];
      listUsersResult.users.forEach(function (userRecord) {
        if (userRecord.providerData.length === 0) {
          anonymousUsers.push(userRecord.uid);
        }
      });

      firebaseAdmin
        .auth()
        .deleteUsers(anonymousUsers)
        .then(function () {
          if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
            // List next batch of users.
            deleteAnonymousUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
          }
        })
    })
}
deleteAnonymousUsers(undefined);
```

Comment: I've used this before and it worked great, but now it fails with "uncaught synt ax Error:  Missing initializer in const declaration". Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [firebase-functions-helper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-functions-helper) package, that can help to delete firebase users in bulk.

```
// Get all users 
firebaseHelper.firebase
    .getAllUsers(100)    
    .then(users => {        
        users.map(user => {
            firebaseHelper.firebase
                .deleteUsers([user.uid]);          
        })   
    })
```

The code above will get 100 users, and delete all of them. If you don't pass the number, the default value is 1000. You can read the instruction on [Github repository](https://github.com/dalenguyen/firebase-functions-helper/blob/master/docs/firebase.md).

Comment: This is still not a bulk delete, which purpose is to do a single transaction. The code of `deleteUsers()` just iterates over the list and deletes the items one by one. Same as any admin command.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem today then I found Firebase Admin SDK. I am using Node.js which is very easy to install, so you can try the following code. It is not a complete answer I know but one can build its own script/application to delete stored uids. Yet, there is no way to retrieve a list, so you have to build one somehow every time you create an anonymous account.

First, download your 'serviceAccountKey.json' which can be done through the Firebase Console (Project Settings). In my case I renamed the download file to a more friendly name and saved to documents folder.

> console.firebase.google.com/project/**yourprojectname**/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk

Useful links:

- [Firebase Admin SDK Setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)
- [Firebase Admin User Management](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users)
- [Firebase Admin Database API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start)

Then, play around using Windows cmd.exe or any other shell. The 'npm install -g' installs firebase-admin globally in your machine.

```
$ npm install firebase-admin -g
$ node
> var admin = require("firebase-admin");
> admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert("./documents/yourprojectname-firebase-admin.json"),
  databaseURL: "https://yourprojectname.firebaseio.com"
});
> var db = admin.database();
// Of course use an existent UID of your choice
> admin.auth().getUser('2w8XEVe7qZaFn2ywc5MnlPdHN90s').then((user) => console.log
(user))
> admin.auth().deleteUser('2w8XEVe7qZaFn2ywc5MnlPdHN90s').then(function() {
    console.log("Successfully deleted user");
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error deleting user:", error);
  });

// To get access to some key/values in your Database:
> var ref = db.ref("users/1234");
> ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. because Firebase doesn't provide any API to delete bulk users but this is how I have deleted all anonymous users.

Download all the  users as json via firebase tool 
**firebase auth:export users --format=json** 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#file_format

You can write a firebase cloud function to trigger or write a action method to trigger

import the  json file in to your file,

```
const Users = require('./users.json'); // ES5 <br>
import Users from './users.json'); // ES6 <br>
```

normally anonymous user doesn't have email so it is easy to delete the record which doesn't have email id

```
Users.users.map(user => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      admin.auth().deleteUser(user.localId).then(() =>{
        console.log("Successfully deleted user");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error deleting user:", error);
      });
    }, 20000);
  });
```

Don't try to reduce the timeout second. It will throw below error

```
Error deleting user: { Error: www.googleapis.com network timeout. Please try again.
```

Comment: your going to delete facebook accounts which have phone number as user ID , aren't you ?

Comment: as @j2emanue mentions and I noticed in trying to export statistics for providers (https://github.com/ddikman/firebase-provider-stats/) the data in the export doesn't clearly state each provider, so be careful with this. Not only are phone number registrations missing but Apple IDs as well

Answer (score 1):

I was writing myself a firebase functions function with Firebase auth.
It works like a charm for me and i can clean with one API call.

```
// Delete all Anon User
exports.deleteUser = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const admin = require("firebase-admin");    

    //initialize auth
    admin.initializeApp(); 
    //create auth instance
    const auth = admin.auth();
    //Get the list of all Users
    const allUsers = await auth.listUsers();  
    //Identify the Anon User give other user null
    const allUsersUID = allUsers.users.map((user) => (user.providerData.length === 0) ? user.uid : null);
    //remove the null
    const filteredallUsersUID = allUsersUID.filter(e => e !== null)
    //delete and answer the API call
    return auth.deleteUsers(filteredallUsersUID).then(() => res.send("All Anon-User deleted"));

  });
```

With this you can just simply call your API URL
https://[Your_API_URL]/deleteUser

Just require basic knowledge of Firebase Functions.
I assume this could be also added to a cron job.

Comment: from the documentation in here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users . using listUsers() without recursive will only retrieve 1000 account, say if the first 1000  no longer have anonymous accounts, then we will never delete any account afterwards

Comment: Good feedback ! did not make it to so many users ... but i will get back to my script when i do ;)

Comment: maybe this will help you a little bit: stackoverflow.com/a/66837805/9605341 :)

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Admin SDK can also [delete multiple users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_multiple_users) at once.

Here is Node.js sample.

```
admin.auth().deleteUsers([uid1, uid2, uid3])
  .then(deleteUsersResult => {
    console.log('Successfully deleted ' + deleteUsersResult.successCount + ' users');
    console.log('Failed to delete ' +  deleteUsersResult.failureCount + ' users');
    deleteUsersResult.errors.forEach(err => {
      console.log(err.error.toJSON());
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Error deleting users:', error);
  });
```

Notice: there is a limitation as [list all users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users).
The maximum number of users allowed to be deleted is **1000** per batch.